# Selecting all records id's from Odoo Contacts listview

Tags: python, xml, listview, odoo-9

I have written some python code in my .py file to display an wizard

```
class DisplayWindow(models.Model):
_inherit = 'res.partner'
wizard_id = fields.Many2one('sale.example_wizard')

def result_to_search(self, cr, uid, active_ids):
    wizard = self.pool['sale.example_wizard'].create(cr, uid, vals={
        'partner_ids': [(6, 0, active_ids)]
    })
    return {
        'name': _('Account Search'),
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_model': 'sale.example_wizard',
        'res_id': wizard,
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'target': 'new',
    }
```

and here is my .xml file

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <!--This xml file is responsible for the server action of displaying the wizard-->
        <record model="ir.actions.server" id="action_search_for_result">
            <field name="name">Account Search</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="sale.model_res_partner"/>
            <field name="code">
                if context.get('active_model') == 'res.partner' and context.get('active_ids'):
                    action = self.pool['res.partner'].result_to_search(cr, uid, context.get('active_ids'))
            </field>
        </record>
        <record model="ir.values" id="search_result">
            <field name="model_id" ref="sale.model_res_partner"/>
            <field name="name">Account Search</field>
            <field name="key2">client_action_multi</field>
            <!--automatically attach action to the dropdown button-->
            <field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.server,' +str(ref('action_search_for_result'))"/>
            <field name="key">action</field>
            <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

My problem is that when I am selecting all customers from cutomers' listview it's only selecting first page contacts and whatever code I have written for wizard's button it's only working for that first page's customers.But my desired result suppose to work on all the customers which I have in database.
Probably I am doing something wrong with this piece of code

```
wizard = self.pool['sale.example_wizard'].create(cr, uid, vals={
            'partner_ids': [(6, 0, active_ids)]
        })
```

Please help me. I can explain more if needed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can get selected record by using following code.

```
wizard = self.pool['sale.example_wizard'].create(cr, uid, vals={
        'partner_ids': [(6, 0, self._context.get('active_ids',[]))]
    })
```

Thanks

Comment: `ValueError: "'res.partner' object has no attribute 'env'" while evaluating
u"if context.get('active_model') == 'res.partner' and context.get('active_ids'):\n                    action = self.pool['res.partner'].distance_to_search(cr, uid, context.get('active_ids'))"`Getting this error for that from xml.Any Idea?

Comment: Yes, You have used old syntax.

Comment: Use this code in code field of xml : if context.get('active_model') == 'res.partner' and context.get('active_ids'):
                    action = self.pool.get('res.partner').result_to_search(cr, uid, context.get('active_ids'))